# Merging using two columns is bringing mismatching results on the second column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge the left side (consider this the first dataframe or data1) with the table on the right (consider this the second dataframe or data2 using R software. I tried using R software using the following code but keep getting a mismatching population.id columns.

```
merged <- merge(data1, data2, by.x=c("article.id", "population.id"),
                by.y=c("article id", "population.id")
```

[image]

Comment: What is your desired output?  I would recommend you use the `dplyr` package in R - it's syntax is much more user friendly for joining data

Comment: `dplyr::left_join(data1, data2, by = c("article id", "population.id"))`

Comment: @dgruenew I wanted to merge the two datasets without getting a mismatch on the population id. One is 1,2,1,2 and the other is 1,1,2,2 which is where I am at now

Comment: @sm925 how does this work when I have different column names? article.id and article id. in my dataset, the population id columns are also different names.

Comment: Try this:`dplyr::inner_join(data1, data2, by = c("article.id" = "article id", "population.id"))` In case `article id` is different. Same way you can add `population id` in `by` of join.